# Full Customer Data is not adding up in quickbooks desktop

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, quickbooks

I am using keith's codeignitor example to add customer data in quickbook desktop from my online pos.

I fetched the data from database and created XML which is perfect and showing all 5109 records. However after running the web service I can only import 165 entries .

Please keep following in mind - 
1)There is no XML breakage . The XML is fine 
2)Webservice time is set to 500 min so no interruption.

Attached is my code for controller and database file -

Controller -

http://quicktotals.com/quickbooks.txt

SQL -

http://quicktotals.com/phppos_people.sql

```
  <?php

class QuickBooks extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // QuickBooks config
        $this->load->config('quickbooks');

        // Load your other models here... 
        //$this->load->model('yourmodel1');
        //$this->load->model('yourmodel2');
        //$this->load->model('yourmodel3');
    }

    /**
     * Generate and return a .QWC Web Connector configuration file
     */
    public function config()
    {
        $name = 'CodeIgniter QuickBooks Demo';          // A name for your server (make it whatever you want)
        $descrip = 'CodeIgniter QuickBooks Demo';       // A description of your server 

        $appurl = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/qbwc';      // This *must* be httpS:// (path to your QuickBooks SOAP server)
        $appsupport = $appurl;      // This *must* be httpS:// and the domain name must match the domain name above

        //$dsn = 'mysql://quicktot_admin:hunter2001@localhost/quicktot_pointofsale';
        //QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn,'vijay','test@1234');

        $username = $this->config->item('quickbooks_user');     // This is the username you stored in the 'quickbooks_user' table by using QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser()

        $fileid = QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC::fileID();        // Just make this up, but make sure it keeps that format
        $ownerid = QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC::ownerID();      // Just make this up, but make sure it keeps that format

        $qbtype = QUICKBOOKS_TYPE_QBFS; // You can leave this as-is unless you're using QuickBooks POS

        $readonly = false; // No, we want to write data to QuickBooks

        $run_every_n_seconds = 600; // Run every 600 seconds (10 minutes)

        // Generate the XML file
        $QWC = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC($name, $descrip, $appurl, $appsupport, $username, $fileid, $ownerid, $qbtype, $readonly, $run_every_n_seconds);
        $xml = $QWC->generate();

        // Send as a file download
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-quickbooks-wc-file.qwc"');
        print($xml);
        exit;

    }

    /**
     * SOAP endpoint for the Web Connector to connect to
     */
    public function qbwc()
    {





    $user = $this->config->item('quickbooks_user');
        $pass = $this->config->item('quickbooks_pass');

        // Memory limit
        ini_set('memory_limit', $this->config->item('quickbooks_memorylimit'));

        // We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
        if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
        {
            // * MAKE SURE YOU SET THIS TO THE CORRECT TIMEZONE! *
            // List of valid timezones is here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
            date_default_timezone_set($this->config->item('quickbooks_tz'));
        }

        // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
        $map = array(
            QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( array( $this, '_addCustomerRequest' ), array( $this, '_addCustomerResponse' )
            ),


            );




        // Catch all errors that QuickBooks throws with this function 
        $errmap = array(
            '*' => array( $this, '_catchallErrors' ),
            );

        // Call this method whenever the Web Connector connects
        $hooks = array(
            QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => array( array( $this, '_loginSuccess' ) ),    // Run this function whenever a successful login occurs
            );

        // An array of callback options
        $callback_options = array();

        // Logging level
        $log_level = $this->config->item('quickbooks_loglevel');

        // What SOAP server you're using 
        $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP;            // The PHP SOAP extension, see: www.php.net/soap
        //$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;      // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

        $soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
            );

        $handler_options = array(
            'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
            'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
            );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

        $driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
            'max_log_history' => 32000, // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
            'max_queue_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
            );

        // Build the database connection string
        $dsn = 'mysql://' . $this->db->username . ':' . $this->db->password . '@' . $this->db->hostname . '/' . $this->db->database;

        // Check to make sure our database is set up 
        if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
        {
            //echo "aaa"; die;

            // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
            QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

            // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
            QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }

        QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
        //echo "bbb"; die;
        // Set up our queue singleton
        QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);

        // Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
        //__construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()

    $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options,$handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);



        $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);

        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER);





        $response = $Server->handle(true, true);




    }

    /**
     * Issue a request to QuickBooks to add a customer
     */
    public function _addCustomerRequest($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
    // Do something to store the form data here
        $this->load->model('Myquickbooks');

        $data = $this->Myquickbooks->getCustomerData();


    $xml ='';

    $xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="11.0"?>';

        $xml .= '<QBXML>';


            $xml .= '<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">';


            foreach ($data as $dta)

            {



                $xml .='<CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>'.$dta['first_name'].'_'.$dta['person_id'].'</Name>
                        <CompanyName>'.$dta['company_name'].'</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>'.$dta['first_name'].'</FirstName>
                        <LastName>'.$dta['last_name'].'</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>'.$dta['address_1'].'</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>'.$dta['address_2'].'</Addr2>
                            <City>'.$dta['city'].'</City>
                            <State>'.$dta['state'].'</State>
                            <PostalCode>'.$dta['zip'].'</PostalCode>
                            <Country>'.$dta['country'].'</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>'.$dta['phone_number'].'</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>'.$dta['phone_number'].'</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>'.$dta['phone_number'].'</Fax>
                        <Email>'.$dta['email'].'</Email>
                        <Contact>'.$dta['phone_number'].'</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>';





                }

        $xml .='</QBXMLMsgsRq>';
        $xml .='</QBXML>';
        $xml = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $xml);

        return $xml;

    }

    /**
     * Handle a response from QuickBooks indicating a new customer has been added
     */ 
    public function _addCustomerResponse($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {


        return true; 
    }


    /**
     * Catch and handle errors from QuickBooks
     */     
    public function _catchallErrors($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
    {


        if ($action == QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER and $errnum == 3100)
    {
        return true; // Ignore this error, all is OK - customer already exists
    }

    // Some other error occurred, stop processing 
    return false;
    }


    /**
     * Whenever the Web Connector connects, do something (e.g. queue some stuff up if you want to)
     */
    public function _loginSuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your MCVE directly to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has numerous problems, and for anyone to help you, you're going to have to fix the problems first. Details:

You're using a 13-year-old version of qbXML. Why? You should use the highest version your QuickBooks supports:

`<?qbxml version="2.0"?>`

You're bundling multiple customers up into a single qbXML request. This is bad -- it destroys any ability you have to actually track and report on errors. Do not do this. Each customer add request should be it's own individual request, with it's own specific entry in the queue. Refer to the documentation.

`foreach ($data as $dta)`

You are specifically bypassing all error checking and error reporting. Why? This makes it *impossible* to know if something went wrong or not.

`return true;`

Fix your code, and then re-post *the actual code* instead of a `.txt` file.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer I updated the code as you asked to but it is still giving me the same issue please check the link. - http://quicktotals.com/check.png  also I have restarted the web connector and still gives this issue even I reinstalled the quickbooks , there is no sales receipt in my code I added it once but now have removed it .You are referring to add one QBXML request , please check the request is different to add each customer . Please help me if I am wrong ,

Comment: Please post your code to SO. Not a link to your code. Post your code to the actual topic.

Comment: And make sure in your code, you've fixed the issues that I've highlighted above.

Comment: Code is still wrong. Each and every customer you want to send to QuickBooks must be queued up separate. If you have 600 customers you want to send, you call ->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $the_customer_id) for each of those 600 customers. You should see 600 records in your quickbooks_queue table. You must NOT have a foreach loop in your addCustomerRequest() method - that method should create qbXML for ONE SINGLE CUSTOMER based on the $ID value (the customer ID for that specific customer). You also should NOT be calling ->enqueue() in the qbwc() function - that will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
    public function sendRequestXML($param = '')
{
    $arrs = user();

    $requests = [];
    $xmlRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        ';

        foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
            // Add customer data for each entry
            $xmlRequest .= '
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . mt_rand() . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>' . $arr['uuid'] . '</Name>
                        <CompanyName>' . $arr['uuid'] . '</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>' . $arr['first_name'] . '</FirstName>
                        <LastName>' . $arr['last_name'] . '</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>' . $arr['role_id'] . '</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                            <City>Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                        <Email>' . $arr['email'] . '</Email>
                        <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            ';
        }

    $xmlRequest .= '</QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>';

    $this->response->sendRequestXMLResult = $xmlRequest;

    return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).